# Static Input Violating MaxLength property of an input box

Tags: html

I have created an input box using `<input type="text" name="username">` for user to input `username`, then i have fixed the length to 5 for some calculation.

`<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="5">`. but when i given the input as static text then it will accept any number of characters.

**Setting max length to 5 means that the input box will hold only 5, then why it holds more than 5 letters when given like this?**
`<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="5" value="12345678910">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp),

> Maxlength eflects the maxlength HTML attribute, containing the maximum length
>   of text (in Unicode code points) that the value can be changed to. The
>   constraint is evaluated only when the value is changed

The key here is that it is **only evaluated when the value is changed**.  You can set the value to anything when you're creating the element.  The effect will take place after you change it.  Try changing the input from your example, and you'll see that it does cap it at 5 characters.